# Using the Modulation property of the Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation

I'm working on a problem:

> Let $X(w)$ be the Fourier transform of $x(t)$. Find the transform of $y(t)=x(5t+3)\sin(2t)$ in terms of X(w).

I am table to take the Fourier transform of $x(5t+3)$ and $\sin(2t)$ just fine using a table and basic time shifting and scaling properties:

$$ \mathscr{F}[x(5t+3)] = \frac{X(\frac{w}{5})}{5} e^{j\frac{3}{5}w}$$

$$ \mathscr{F}[\sin(2t)] = \frac{\pi}{j}[\delta{(w-2)}-\delta{(w+2)}]$$

But the question is then how to "combine" these two results? I was thinking of using the modulation property:

$$ \mathscr{F}[x(t)m(t)] = \frac{1}{2\pi}X(w)*M(w) $$
where $*$ denotes convolution.

However, I'd much rather prefer to note convolve these two function together as it would be quite a task (by hand at least). Surely there must be a better way?

**EDIT**: MSE gives me a magical ability to solve a problem that I otherwise would not figure out shortly after posting a question.

I have overlooked two things that are extremely useful here:

1. Euler's inverse identity for sine
   $$sin(2t) = \frac{1}{2j}[e^{j2t}-e^{-j2t}] $$
2. Frequency shift property of Fourier Transform
   $$ \mathscr{F}[x(t)e^{jw_0t}] = X(w-w_0) $$

Comment: Convolving with a delta is indeed a pretty simple task!

Comment: @Dirk You're right. 15 minutes in the penalty box for me.

Comment: I think your expression for sin in terms of e is wrong, the second term should be negated.  Probably just a typo, you're right on track otherwise

Comment: @MarkKCowan Nice catch -- looks like I typed it wrong because I have the minus over here on my "cheat sheet".

Comment: Not magical. Google "Rubber duck debugging" for something similar.

Comment: @DanielFischer Nice name for it!